# facebook App - where should I set redirect URL

Tags: php, facebook

I've used facebook apps before but they have changed app settings and I can't find where I should set app redirect url.
I'm using laravel 5 and in `services.php` I have:

```html
'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => 'my_client_ip_here', 
        'client_secret' => 'my_client_secret', 
        'redirect' => 'projectURL/handleProviderCallback/facebook'
    ],
```

I got this error:
`URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.`

But I can't find which setting I should change - where it is redirect URL.

Answer (score 1):

> But I can't find which setting I should change - where it is redirect URL.

Those settings are now located under Products -> Facebook Login.

If you don’t see that in the sidebar already, then you have to add it first.